# Perfect Square from Geometric Progression

Tags: number-theory, geometric-progressions

This question is from QuantGuide(namely Geometrical Progression):
Write out a series of whole numbers in geometrical progression with at least 3 terms, starting from
1, so that the numbers add up to a square. The common ratio must be strictly larger than 1.

Give the answer in the form of the smallest square number in which a progression can be written.
My Approach:
I have arrived at this position
\begin{equation}
1+r+r^2+r^3+...+r^{n-1} = b^2
\end{equation}
where r,n,b are some integers and $r>1$. But I can't proceed further. Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you should insert a $+ r$ between the first two terms of the sum on the left-hand side. With that correction in place, it may be helpful to multiply both sides by $r - 1$, to give $r^n - 1 = b^2 (r - 1)$.

Comment: They ask for geometric and it hasn't to consecutive

Comment: Did you forget the term $r$ in your statement or did you miss it on purpose?

Comment: @Severus'Constant sorry for the error. I have now corrected it.

Comment: It is easy to show that there is no such sequence for $n=3$. Generalising it for any $n$ might be difficult.

Comment: @Sahaj What do you have in mind for $n=3$

Comment: @OlderAmateur, rather elementary idea: $$r^2 < r^2+r+1(=b^2)<r^2+2r+1$$ since $r>1$. Take square roots and you show that $b$ is between two consecutive integers.

Comment: $b$ can be even. Also there's more solutions than just $r=3$. There's $20^2 = 1+7+49+343$.

Answer (score 0):

Smallest square number is $121$

$$1 + 3 + 9 + 27 + 81 = 121$$

Proof: Try perfect square numbers less than $121$ and see that you cannot write them that way.

This question relates to consecutive powerful numbers, a concept not yet fully understood. (because $r^n$ is powerful and $r^n-1$ is potentially a powerful number)

There is also an open question: "Can three consecutive numbers be powerful?"

Answer (score 0):

There are **only two** square numbers which can be expressed as a sum of consecutive powers of integers. These are $121$ and $400$.

$$1+3+9+27+81=121$$

$$1+7+49+343 = 400$$

Comment: Why so? Is there a formal proof of the above claim?

Comment: I wrote a C++ brute force code which runs in $O(n*r)$ time. I checked for all r = $2$ to $10^5$ and number of terms from $3$ till $1000$. You can check the code here (and increase the parameters further if you want) : https://github.com/devansh-agarwal121/Random-codes/blob/main/sum_of_GP_perfect_square.cpp